# Libgdx: Why do actions in Actions.parallel keep repeat themselves?

Tags: java, libgdx, action

I have been trying to make a "parallel action" with two actions in it, but the second Action (which is a manual "new Action()" thing) keep repeating itself until the first Action is done, although it only has to be executed until it returns "true".

It is a little bit hard to explain so I am sorry :/

The second Action has to keep repeating itself until the "alpha" is bigger than a certain value. After it reaches that value, it should return "true" and stop repeating.
But it just continues repeating itself, although it returns a "true".

What am I doing wrong?

```
Actions.parallel(
                        Actions.scaleTo(1, 1, 1.5f, Interpolation.circleIn),
                        new Action() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean act(float delta) {
                                pointLight.setColor(r, g, b, (alpha < PlayScreen.score/50 ? alpha += delta/1.5f: PlayScreen.score/50));                         
                                if (alpha > PlayScreen.score/50) {
                                    body.setActive(true);
                                    System.out.println("Debug"); //To check if it keeps repeating
                                    return true;
                                } else {
                                    return false;
                                }

                            }
                        })
```

Comment: I don't see any issues in the code you posted, but maybe there's something in how you're applying this action.

Comment: This parallel Action is in a SequenceAction class which is in a  RepeatedAction class. May that cause a problem? How can I avoid it?

Comment: Anything can cause a problem if there's a bug in your code. We need to see more context.